# I dont understand my result after using findAssocs in R

Tags: r, twitter, tm

I have a dataset with tweets. I am searching the Dutch word 'verhuizen'. When I run the following code I get two tweets out of my dataset containing the word.

```
Aah_verhuizen=Aa_en_Hunze[grepl('verhuizen', Aa_en_Hunze$twt_txt),]
```

[1] @Isaa_0592 verhuizen? Waarheen dan?

[2] Yes de school blijft hier in het dorp, nu gaan we niet meer verhuizen dit jaar! ??

Then I run the code to find the most associated word with 'verhuizen' using findAssocs of the package tm.

```
verhuizen <- c('verhuizen')
Aah.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(Aa_en_Hunze$twt_txt))
Aah.corpus <- tm_map(Aah.corpus, tolower) 
Aah.corpus <- tm_map(Aah.corpus, removePunctuation)
Aah.dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Aah.corpus)
Aah_ass_verhuizen <- findAssocs(Aah.dtm, verhuizen, 0.10)
```

My result of this code is:

waarheen      0.58

dorp          0.24

isaa0592      0.24

gebeuren      0.22

blijft        0.15

I dont know how findAssocs calculates the scores. For example: Why does the word 'waarheen' get such a high score. It is only metioned once in one of the two tweets. I dont understand how findAssocs calculates the scores for the associated words. I searched the help function, google and stackoverflow but have not found a satisfying answer. Does anyone know?

I think the answer I am searching is in the following lines of code. Which I got from the following question.

[Math of tm::findAssocs how does this function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267199/math-of-tmfindassocs-how-does-this-function-work)

```
function (x, term, corlimit) 
sort(round(x[term, which(x[term, ] > corlimit)], 2), decreasing = TRUE)
<environment: namespace:tm>
```

What does it do? I will try to figure it out myself by running parts of the sentence.

```
test <- Aah.dtm['verhuizen', which(Aah.dtm['verhuizen', ]> 0.10)],2
```

Why does this give me the following error?

Error: unexpected ',' in "test <- Aah.dtm['verhuizen', which(Aah.dtm['verhuizen', ]> 0.10)],"

Comment: Shouldn't this really be a question posed to the authors and maintainer of the package????? It's not a coding question, is it? Unless, of course you think a coding question is:  1) search for the unnamed package and 2) then read through the code and 3) then build you a personally constructed tutorial. That's not really how I understand SO.

Comment: It is a question to the code behind the function. I might be wrong as a rooky programmer but I see that as a coding question. I dont know where another place is with such knowledge that might be able to answer the question I ask. You bring up a good point that adding the package to the question would be smart. I dont expect a whole lot. Actually I am hoping someone has used and understood this function and could without a lot of trouble explain it to me. Perhaps someone even had the same doubt in his mind and figured it out.

Comment: Then post some code (from teh package)  and ask for an explanation. Show some effort.

Comment: I think I found the code in an answer you gave to someone else once here on stackoverflow. I have added the lines of code I think are important to me in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how the function works, the easiest way is to look at the documentation. The main page is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html), with a function reference [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf) and a nice vignette [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf).

If those do not give you enough detail, you can always consult the [source code](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tm_0.5-10.tar.gz), which happens to be available under GPL.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpfull, yet I am still not able to explain how this function scores the associated words.